# is it possible to create an attachment box to fetch FilePath using C# console as in Windows Form?

Tags: c#, console, windows-forms-designer

so I have this code that fetches me lines and columns from an ExcelPath(path/to/excel/file.xlsx) and shows it in the Console, but going forward I will make other uses of the lines and columns imported from excel. I would like to instead of including the ExcelPath using the `Console.ReadLine()` use it as the `OpenFileDialog` of the Windows Form **would it be possible** to do something similar in the console?

```
public void ImportExcel()
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert path to excel file");
        Console.WriteLine("ex : path/to/excel/file.xlsx");

        string excelPath = Console.ReadLine();
        using var stream = File.Open(excelPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);

        if (reader.Name != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Loading sheet name: {reader.Name}");
        }

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(reader.GetValue(i) + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add reference

```
System.Windows.Forms;
System.Drawing.Common;
```

Full sample code for .NET Core 3.1

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OpenFileDialogTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Create an instance of the OpenFileDialog class
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            // Set the initial directory and filter for the file dialog
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            // Show the dialog and get the result
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

            // If the user clicked OK, get the selected file path and read the file
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
                Console.WriteLine($"Selected file: {filePath}");

                // Read the contents of the file
                string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                Console.WriteLine("File contents:");
                Console.WriteLine(fileContents);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No file selected.");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Full sample code for .NET 6 top level statement

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// Use a helper method to run the OpenFileDialog in a separate STA thread
string selectedFilePath = await RunStaThread(() =>
{
    // Create a new instance of the OpenFileDialog class
    using OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
    {
        // Set the initial directory and filter for the file dialog
        InitialDirectory = "C:\\",
        Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    };

    // Show the dialog and get the result
    return openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK
        ? openFileDialog.FileName // If the user clicked OK, return the selected file path
        : null; // Otherwise, return null
});

// Check if a file was selected and display its contents
if (selectedFilePath != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Selected file: {selectedFilePath}");

    // Read the contents of the file
    string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(selectedFilePath);
    Console.WriteLine("File contents:");
    Console.WriteLine(fileContents);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No file selected.");
}

// Wait for user input before exiting the console application
Console.ReadLine();

// Helper method to run code in a separate STA thread
static async Task<T> RunStaThread<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    // Create a new TaskCompletionSource object to await the result of the STA thread
    TaskCompletionSource<T> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

    // Create a new thread and set its apartment state to STA
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            // Run the provided code on the STA thread and set the result of the TaskCompletionSource object
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(func());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // If an exception is thrown, set the exception on the TaskCompletionSource object
            taskCompletionSource.SetException(ex);
        }
    });

    // Set the apartment state of the new thread to STA
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

    // Start the new thread
    thread.Start();

    // Await the result of the STA thread and return it
    return await taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```